# JupyterLab: Save As ".py" not avaialble

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm trying to export the .ipynb into .py file, however, I'm not getting the option in the drop down. Can someone help what could be the reason for that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which notebook version are you using? If there's no option, you can maybe do this in the command line.

```
ipython nbconvert --to python *.ipynb
```